# Basic SSL through router Setup

Tags: ssl, certificate, router, nat

A basic question for SSL if I may...

I have a subsonic server that can use an SSL cert behind a NAT router.  Let's assume the NAT router has the name gateway.mydomain.com and my subsonic server has the name subsonic.mydomain.com.  If I want the subosnic server to use a cert, do I use the name of the subsonic server or the NAT router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want clients to connect with SSL to your subsonic server, the certificate needs to match the domain of the server so you will want to use subsonic.mydomain.com and have the router port forward whatever ports are needed for subsonic. Also the IP of subsonic.mydomain.com would need to be the routers IP (unless you setup the router to allow  the subsonic server to have a WAN IP address.)